# How to delete a panel in Grafana 2.5

Tags: monitoring, data-visualization, grafana

There seems to be no way to do it. There is a 'delete row' functionality, but not for a panel in the row. As a workaround, I create a new row, move panel there and then delete, which I think is going too far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that a cross in top right corner is not to close the popup window, but to delete the panel ...

[image: Menu]

Comment: I'd recommend you opening an issue in their issue tracker to ask them to add back the Remove option to the panel contextual menu, or clarify what the top-right cross sign means in the UI.

Comment: I did already: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3207. In fact this is how I found the answer.

Comment: When I delete one of the panels like this and "save", the next time the dashboard is loaded, all other panels are gone as well (== the complete row/section is empty).

Answer (score 1):

I have an older version of Grafana, but I can find a "Remove" option when I click on a panel title.

[image: Panel dropdown]

Comment: Unfortunately, they changed the menu in 2.5 and there is no 'Remove' option anymore.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.